# sort entire 2d vector on the basis of a certain row

Tags: c++, sorting, vector

I am interested to sort the entire 2d vector on the basis of second row. I tried some code which sort only second row, however, i want it for the entire 2d vector.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector> 
#include<algorithm> 
int main()
{
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > vect{{3, 5, 1},
                                         {4, 8, 6},
                                         {7, 2, 9}};
    int m = vect.size();
    int n = vect[0].size();
    sort(vect[1].begin(), vect[1].end());
    std::cout << "After sorting :\n";
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<n ;j++)
            std::cout << vect[i][j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The output come like:

```
3 5 1 
4 6 8 
7 2 9
```

But I want it to be

```
3 1 5
4 6 8
7 9 2
```

Comment: What does "on the basis of second row" mean, exactly? Your expected output looks like you just want to sort every row by itself.

Comment: The request is to reorder each row in the same way as the second row is reordered during sorting.

Comment: @ChristianHackl Thanks!! No, not every row by itself exactly, but sort second row and get other values in the corresponding rows shifted too

Comment: Ah, I understand now! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a function which transposes the vector, so it should modify {{3, 5, 1}, {4, 8, 6}, {7, 2, 9}} into {{3,4,7},{5,8,2},{1,6,9}}. Transpose the vector with your function, then sort the vector with custom comparator comparing the second elements of rows. Then call the transpose function again.

The transpose function could look like

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > transpose(std::vector< std::vector<int> >& vect)
{
 std::vector< std::vector<int> > transposed(vect[0].size(), std::vector<int>());
 for (size_t i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i)
  for (size_t j = 0; j < vect[0].size(); ++j)
    transposed[j].push_back(vect[i][j]);
 return transposed;
}
```

Then the entire code would be

```
vect = transpose(vect);                                     
std::sort(vect.begin(), vect.end(), 
  [](const std::vector<int>& lhs, const std::vector<int>& rhs)
     {return lhs[1] < rhs[1];});                                     
vect = transpose(vect);
```

If a vector is square then the transposition can be done in place making the solution much more effective then this general one.

Comment: Thanks, but a bit difficult for novice

Comment: Thanks for giving more details. Do you mean number of row and columns should be same?? if so, that is not my case.

Comment: I modified the answer so it supports non-square vectors too.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I declare `std::vector< std::vector<int>& > vect(2, std::vector< int> ())` as pass by reference, do I need to change anything. I get some errors if I declare like this

Comment: @Hashim find more about your problem at https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=0ahUKEwikltv5idjRAhWM8CYKHf3nCrAQFgggMAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F922360%2Fwhy-cant-i-make-a-vector-of-references&usg=AFQjCNG5rL5v4pRoYGXDdnZNsmI9jPQLCA&sig2=2DKNpJrg3IAbdCLMwkBIdQ

Answer (score 1):

The structure of question won't allow us to use built-in sort function. Because, custom sort will only provides "rows". And you can compare "rows" only.

But there are some alternative ways to accomplish that.

For example you can do that by transposing vector of vector.

"Transpose > Sort by column > Transpose" may solve your problem.

But my solution is based on another dynamic.

1. Sort nth column and keep indexes as array. (n is the position of ordered row)
2. Using the array defined at step 1, sort all rows one by one.

http://cpp.sh/4dkzg

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector> 
#include<algorithm> 

using namespace std;

template <typename T>
vector<size_t> sort_indexes(const vector<T> &v) {

  // initialize original index locations
  vector<size_t> idx(v.size());
  iota(idx.begin(), idx.end(), 0);

  // sort indexes based on comparing values in v
  sort(idx.begin(), idx.end(),
       [&v](size_t i1, size_t i2) {return v[i1] < v[i2];});

  return idx;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector< std::vector<int> > vect{{3, 5, 1, 2},
                                         {4, 8, 6, 1},
                                         {7, 2, 9, 5}};
    int m = vect.size();
    int n = vect[0].size();

    int sortByRow = 1; // starts from 0, if 1 => order by using 2nd row.

    /* generate reference for our actual sort operation */
    std::vector<size_t> indexSort = sort_indexes(vect[sortByRow]);

    /* sort each row using our reference vector */
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {      
        int temp[n];
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
            temp[j] = vect[i][indexSort[j]];

        // Copy back temp[] to vector
        for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
            vect[i][j]  = temp[j];

    }

    std::cout << "After sorting :\n";
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<n ;j++)
            std::cout << vect[i][j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reorder-a-array-according-to-given-indexes/ (if you want to apply in-place sorting, there are some fixes)

Answer (score 0):

You could make an `std::vector` of `std::pair<int,int>` where in the first variable of the i-th element of the vector you have the i-th value of the second row while in the second variable you have the value of the index i.

Then you sort that vector based on the first values of the pairs. That way you can make a new 2D vector where in every row you order the elements based on the second value of the pairs, which are the old indices.

```
std::vector< std::vector<int> > vect{{ 3, 5, 1 },{ 4, 8, 6 },{ 7, 2, 9 }};
std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> row;

for (int i = 0; i < vect[1].size(); ++i){
    row.push_back({vect[1][i],i});
}
sort(row.begin(), row.end());

std::vector< std::vector<int> > sorted;
std::vector<int> sortedRow;
for (int i = 0; i < vect.size(); ++i){
    for (int j = 0; j < vect[i].size(); ++j){
        sortedRow.push_back(vect[i][row[j].second]);
    }
    sorted.push_back(sortedRow);
    sortedRow.clear();
}
```

You have to `#include <utility>`.

Answer (score 0):

This code is very dirty. but exactly is the same code you want.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>

std::vector< std::vector<int> > vect = { {3, 5, 1}, {4, 8, 6}, {7, 2, 9} };

int findInVector(std::vector<int> input, int temp)
{
    for(int i=0;i<input.size();i++)
    {
        if(input[i] == temp)
        {
            return i;
        }
    }
}

bool myfunction (int i,int j)
{

    bool ret;

    if(i<j)
    {
        int i_pos = findInVector( vect[1], i);
        int j_pos = findInVector( vect[1], j);

        int temp  = vect[0][i_pos];
        vect[0][i_pos] = vect[0][j_pos];
        vect[0][j_pos] = temp;

        temp  = vect[2][i_pos];
        vect[2][i_pos] = vect[2][j_pos];
        vect[2][j_pos] = temp;

        ret = true;
    }
    else
    {
        ret = false;
    }

    return ret;
}

int main()
{
    int m = vect.size();
    int n = vect[0].size();
    sort(vect[1].begin(), vect[1].end(), myfunction);
    std::cout << "After sorting :\n";
    for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<n ;j++)
            std::cout << vect[i][j] << " ";
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```